# Нужна помощь по заданию с использованием библиотеки jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добавить к зарплате символ валюты, значение 1000-3999 сделать курсивом, 4000-5999 - подчеркнутыми, 6000+ - жирными.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Лабораторна робота №12</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 50px;
        }
        table {
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        td{
            min-width: 50px;
            padding: 2px 10px;
        }
        td:first-child{
            text-align: left;
        }
  td:person{
text-align: right;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document.body).ready(function () {
            $('tr td:first-child').each(function(i,elem) {
    if ($(this).next().text()=='Жін.') {
      $(this).css("color", "pink");
    }
    if ($(this).next().text()=='Чол.') {
       $(this).css("color", "blue");
    }
  });
$('table tr td:first-child')
            .filter(function(index, text){
                let row1 = +$(this).parent().children(":eq(4)").text();
                let row2 = +$(this).parent().children(":eq(5)").text();
                return row2==1 || row1==0 || row2  && row1  ;
            })
        .append("");


        $('table tr td:first-child')
            .filter(function(index, text){
                let row1 = +$(this).parent().children(":eq(4)").text();
                let row2 = +$(this).parent().children(":eq(5)").text();
                return row2==0 || row1==1 || row2  && row1  ;
            })
        .append("");
            // write your code here
});
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="mytable" border=1><tr><th>Ім'я</th><th>Стать</th><th>Вік</th><th>Одружений(a)</th><th>Сини</th><th>Доньки</th><th>Дом. тварина</th><th>Зарплата</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Додковська Яна</td><td>Жін.</td><td>42</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>метелик</td><td>334</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Яцуненкова Юлія</td><td>Жін.</td><td>31</td><td>Ні</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>пацюк</td><td>788</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Білай Олександр</td><td>Чол.</td><td>51</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>жаба</td><td>3821</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ярюшенк Дмитро</td><td>Чол.</td><td>62</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>кіт</td><td>822</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Сольвейстров Марк</td><td>Чол.</td><td>61</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>скорпіон</td><td>348</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Вєльковський Олександр</td><td>Чол.</td><td>66</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>метелик</td><td>722</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Каретан Андрій</td><td>Чол.</td><td>44</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>метелик</td><td>200</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Гіроєва Дарина</td><td>Жін.</td><td>62</td><td>Так</td><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>-</td><td>5743</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Тяфф Іван</td><td>Чол.</td><td>46</td><td>Так</td><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>миша</td><td>7843</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Гем Денис</td><td>Чол.</td><td>37</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>3</td><td>ящірка</td><td>1881</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ткачюк Станіслав</td><td>Чол.</td><td>21</td><td>Ні</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>миша</td><td>270</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Мазєренко Олександр</td><td>Чол.</td><td>20</td><td>Так</td><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>равлик</td><td>8307</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нуу... если сильно хочется привязать скрипт именно к разметке, это будет выглядеть так:

`parseFloat()` здесь не обязателен. Он просто берет строку, которая начинается с числа, отбрасывает лишнее и оставляет только число. Т.е. из `'5000 рублей'` оставит только число 5000, которое можно сравнивать с другими числами. Разницу между "строго меньше" и "меньше или равно" - наверно и так знаете.

```js
$(document.body).ready(function () {

//Добавлено:
$('table tr td:last-child').each(function(){
  $(this).text( $(this).text() + ' $' );//или какой-то другой символ...

  let val = parseFloat( $(this).text() );
  if( val < 4000 && val > 999 ){
    $(this).html( '<i>' + $(this).html() + '</i>' );
  } else if( val >= 4000 && val < 6000 ) {
    $(this).html( '<u>' + $(this).html() + '</u>' );
  } else if( val >= 6000 ) {
    $(this).html( '<b>' + $(this).html() + '</b>' );
  }
});

//Дальше не трогал... но не выдержал и поменял цвета.

            $('tr td:first-child').each(function(i,elem) {
    if ($(this).next().text()=='Жін.') {
      $(this).css("color", "#ac007c"); // Темно-малиновый
    }
    if ($(this).next().text()=='Чол.') {
       $(this).css("color", "#045acf"); // Синий
    }
  });
$('table tr td:first-child')
            .filter(function(index, text){
                let row1 = +$(this).parent().children(":eq(4)").text();
                let row2 = +$(this).parent().children(":eq(5)").text();
                return row2==1 || row1==0 || row2  && row1  ;
            })
        .append("");


        $('table tr td:first-child')
            .filter(function(index, text){
                let row1 = +$(this).parent().children(":eq(4)").text();
                let row2 = +$(this).parent().children(":eq(5)").text();
                return row2==0 || row1==1 || row2  && row1  ;
            })
        .append("");
            // write your code here
});
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 50px;
        }
        table {
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        td{
            min-width: 50px;
            padding: 2px 10px;
        }
        td:first-child{
            text-align: left;
        }
  td:person{
text-align: right;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="mytable" border=1><tr><th>Ім'я</th><th>Стать</th><th>Вік</th><th>Одружений(a)</th><th>Сини</th><th>Доньки</th><th>Дом. тварина</th><th>Зарплата</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Додковська Яна</td><td>Жін.</td><td>42</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>метелик</td><td>334</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Яцуненкова Юлія</td><td>Жін.</td><td>31</td><td>Ні</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>пацюк</td><td>788</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Білай Олександр</td><td>Чол.</td><td>51</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>жаба</td><td>3821</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ярюшенк Дмитро</td><td>Чол.</td><td>62</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>кіт</td><td>822</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Сольвейстров Марк</td><td>Чол.</td><td>61</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>скорпіон</td><td>348</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Вєльковський Олександр</td><td>Чол.</td><td>66</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>метелик</td><td>722</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Каретан Андрій</td><td>Чол.</td><td>44</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>метелик</td><td>200</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Гіроєва Дарина</td><td>Жін.</td><td>62</td><td>Так</td><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>-</td><td>5743</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Тяфф Іван</td><td>Чол.</td><td>46</td><td>Так</td><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>миша</td><td>7843</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Гем Денис</td><td>Чол.</td><td>37</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>3</td><td>ящірка</td><td>1881</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ткачюк Станіслав</td><td>Чол.</td><td>21</td><td>Ні</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>миша</td><td>270</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Мазєренко Олександр</td><td>Чол.</td><td>20</td><td>Так</td><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>равлик</td><td>8307</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь) А как добавить к колонке зарплата символ валюты?

Comment: Добавил в ответ (евсевственно, пробел перед символом можно и убрать). Но задолбаетесь работать с такими комбо-селекторами... с классами работать тупо легче) Но это дело можно было бы и без скрипта, в CSS прописать `table tr td:last-child:after { content: ' $'; }`

Comment: @АняЕськина  там же есть символ валюты

Comment: Извините. сразу не заметила)

Answer (score 0):

Как и в предыдущем вопросе - если работу можно вынести в CSS - выносите.

```js
$(".slr").each(function(){
  let v = +$(this).text();
  if(v > 6000) $(this).addClass("slr-6000")
  else if(v > 4000) $(this).addClass("slr-4000")
  else if(v > 1000) $(this).addClass("slr-1000");
});
```

```css
.slr::before {
  content: "$";
}

.slr-1000 { font-style: italic; }
.slr-4000 { text-decoration: underline; }
.slr-6000 { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="mytable" border=1>
  <tr><th>Ім'я</th><th>Зарплата</th></tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Додковська Яна</td><td class="slr">334</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Яцуненкова Юлія</td><td class="slr">1500</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Білай Олександр</td><td class="slr">4500</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ярюшенк Дмитро</td><td class="slr">7000</td></tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```